# Incorrect instance of spring starter project getting created in STS

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I am using STS version: `3.8.0.RELEASE`; Build Id: `201606301029`

When I create a Spring Starter Project, it should by default have Java, Spring and Maven nature. But it only has Maven nature and the folder structure is also not in accordance with Maven nature (`src/main/java`). Also, the POM shows error message that unable to locate parent POM `spring-boot-starter-parent 1.3.6.RELEASE`.

I observed that while creation of a Spring Starter project , it should download all the necessary dependencies from `starter.zip`, but its not downloading from my STS ide.

Is this a setup issue or some network related issue?

Comment: Hmmm... Hard to tell what exactly is going wrong here. Can you post some detailed steps how to reproduce this? Maybe starting with a fresh STS 3.8.0 distro installation?

Comment: Making a wild guess. Something is preventing maven/m2e to connect to maven central to fetch artefacts. Could be many different things. A firewall issue, a temporary network issue, local maven caching issue. Start by closing STS then delete maven local repo and reopen STS. Try doing 'maven update project' from project context menu. If it still doesn't work maybe there will be some more helpful errors.

Comment: BTW the artefact that can't be found definitely exists in maven central (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.3.6.RELEASE) so that's why I'm thinking its more likely a issue getting acces to it than something wrong with the project itself